# Overwrite return address In C with a unsigned long variable using buffer overflow

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I am trying to overwrite the data using **strcpy()** function with that stack protection off. The problem I encounter here is that using strcpy() to write an unsigned long variable(address) would change the value because of little-endian(?). I want to know if there is any way to copy the exact value of unsigned long into the stack using strcpy() or I should use another function instead.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// some shellcode in format like "\x31\xc0"
const char shellcode[] = ...;

// vulnerable function bof
void bof(char *str){
    char buffer[12];
    printf("Come into function bof\n");
    strcpy(buffer, str);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char buffer[517];
    //random filling of buffer that may not be necessary
    strcpy(buffer,"abcdefghijkl1234");

    //I believe buffer[16] is the location of return addr when the program goes in bof()
    //I write the shell code into buffer[20] first
    strcpy(&buffer[20],shellcode);

    //Trying to make value of location buffer[16] into address of buffer[20]
    strcpy(&buffer[16],&buffer[20]);


    // bof is called here
    bof(buffer);
    printf("Exit from function bof\n");
}
```

Comment: For copying arbitrary data, you should be using `memcpy()` rather than `strcpy()`.

Comment: I'm a little uncertain of what you are trying to do, but endianness is not the issue.  Please give use a better explanation of what you hope to accomplish. Also,  As Ken Y-N said you should use memcpy for arbitrary data, so you can control the size.

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy(&buffer[16],&buffer[20]);` will copy shellcode to `&buffer[16]`, not the address of shellcode, which is `&buffer[20]`. You have to translate `&buffer[20]` into byte array then copy it to `&buffer[16]`.

For example, `&buffer[20] == 0xbfff1234`. Then you should have a `char shell_addr[5] = "\x34\x12\xff\xbf\x00"` and do `strcpy(&buffer[16], a);`